# load xib UIView from Textfield.inputview

Tags: swift, xib, nib

I have a custom xib (UIView) with a UIPickerView and a Done button.

I am trying to load it as an inputview of a textfield.

If I have the xib as a UIView and have a UIView Class.swift file, I do not know where to put the NSBundle... to associate the swift file with the xib

If I make the xib a UIViewController and have a UIViewController.swift, I can associate the two (or so I think) but in my main viewcontroller.swift my textfield.inputview won't take an instance of the UIViewController as an input view (probably because it is not a UIView).

I'm new to swift programming and still trying to figure out xibs, storyboards and writing views/buttons etc. programmatically.

I can do what I want by programmatically defining a view, adding a UIPicker and button to that view and assigning an action to the button (view.EndEditing = true) which I can then set as an input view, but I would like to do it via a xib so I can more easily setup the autolayout.

Here is the UIViewController version version:

#### pickWithDoneViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class pickerWithDoneViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet weak var floorPicker: UIPickerView!
  var myArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

  //INITIAL METHODS
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("pickerWithDoneViewController", owner: self, options: nil)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  // PICKER METHODS
  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(floorPicker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func pickerView(floorPicker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
  }

  func pickerView(floorPicker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return myArray[row]
  }

  // BUTTON METHODS
  @IBAction func floorPickerDone(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.endEditing(true)
  }
```

#### pickerWithDoneViewController.xib:

[image]

#### Main ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var floorPickerTextField: UITextField!
  let pickerInputView = pickerWithDoneViewController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    floorPickerTextField.inputview = pickerInputView
    //***ERROR***:  Cannot assign a value of type 'pickerWithDoneViewController to a value of type UIView?
  }
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
}
```

Thanks for looking and sorry if I'm making simple mistakes.  I'm trying to learn by coding.

Comment: you can't load oneView into another view i.e. you wan't load the xib file content into main storyboard UIView . Also Xib file content execute  only one's in life of application till it terminates.

Comment: @Rizwan Do you mean specifically that you cannot add a uiview xib into another uiview?  Because I think you can add uiviews as subviews of uiviews as many as you like in storyboard (drawing one view into another view) or programatically (self.view.addSubview(v1), v1.addSubview(v2), v2.addSubview(v3)...

Answer (score 0):

u can add as many view u want in a single storyboard(Viewcontroller class). but u can't load one ViewController into another ViewController as swift support `single inheritance` only  .
In  your code

```
let pickerInputView = pickerWithDoneViewController()
```

at this line u want to create a instance of class which is also extends UIViewController class make it as multiple inheritance